# How to bind value inside the input field?

Tags: php, html, view, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter-3 for developing the  web apps, i have one update or edit form i am passing the data to the view file but the data is not binding in UI (input field is empty),can you help me where did i mistake..?

**print_r($data)**

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 14 [book_id] => test_565 [book_name] => Pelerin [book_number] => 2323232 [address] => ssss  [status] => 1 ) )
```

**controller.php**

```
$data = $res->stations;
//return print_r($data);
$this->load->view('edit-book',$data);
```

**edit-book.php**

```
 <input type="text" name="product_title" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $data[stations]->book_name;?>" id="exampleInputName1" placeholder="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the key value based before sending the data to view file like following

```
$data['data'] = $res->stations;
```

In view file

```
value="<?php echo $data[0]->book_name;?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in your controller,

```
$data = array("stations"=>$res->stations);
$this->load->view('edit-book',$data);
```

And in view,

```
<input type="text" name="product_title" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $stations[0]->book_name;?>" id="exampleInputName1" placeholder="">
```

Comment: i tried this one but it's empty

Comment: your doing it a wrong way, I will explain in the answer one more correction.

Comment: can you try this now @dev

Comment: i tried this one but the value is not coming